# Tool to track and manage versions and dependencies of project components (exe, dll, ssis etc)

Tags: .net, soa

My company is moving into a Service Oriented and modular development structure.  So far it is looking great and working well.

One problem we can see starting to happen is keeping track of which programs are referencing various Dlls and (WCF) services.  As dlls and services get updated, there will be applications using the older versions.

We are finding that keeping a plain test list of dependencies and product manifests (lists of components in a project)works.  But it is not flexible.

A plain text list cannot be queried and manipulated to pull out needed information.

**So, it leaves me wondering if there are any tools to track versions of files and the dependencies between them?**

If there are several tools, I would (of course) prefer a free/open source solution.

In case it matters, we use TFS for our source control and auto builds.

Comment: You're looking for a Configuration Management tool ([Service Asset and Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library#Service_asset_and_configuration_management) in ITIL terms).

Answer (score 1):

This topic itself is quite complicated and there is no general or standard approach available for this. I can highly recommend to read a book [Continious Delivery](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Continuous-Delivery-Deployment-Automation-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321601912), there you will also find a list of available tools and a proper explanation of how to do things correctly. Keep in mind this will take significant ammount of time, but from the other hand will make your life so much easier.

In a nutshell, you will need to have:

1. List of all products (binaries, msi, dlls, etc) available within your company
2. A list of all possible configurations for the products
3. Versions available of any product
4. List of environments (staging, UAT testing, production, etc)

You will also need to have a place where you can select a product of particular version, it's configuration and deploy it via one button click to the selected environment. This user interface shall also allow you to see which product (version and configuration) is deployed to which environment. Behind the scene, the tool will just call the scripts that you wrote to perform custom deployment.

In terms of tools, there are quite a few things that you will need:

1. CI server(Go, TeamCity, TFS)
2. Build managements scripts, such as MSBuild, NAnt, etc.
3. Tools like Puppet or CMDB for configuration management
4. Deployment scripts, like Powershell